# How to display asterisk for input in Java?

Tags: java

I need to write a little program in Java that asks a person to enter a Pin Code.
So I need the Pin to be hidden with asterisks (*) instead of the numbers. How can I do that?

So far, this is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class codePin {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int pinSize = 0;

        do{
            Scanner pin = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Pin: ");
            int str = pin.nextInt();
            String s = new Integer(str).toString();

            pinSize = s.length();

            if(pinSize != 4){
            System.out.println("Your pin must be 4 integers");
            } else {
            System.out.println("We're checking if Pin was right...");
            }

        }while(pinSize != 4);
    }
}
```

Actually this program works for now, but I want to add a functionality to display Pin like "* * * *" or "* * *" etc... (in the console when the Person enters is own Pin).
I found something to entirely hide the Pin, but I do not want this. I want the Pin with asterisks

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: check these out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076165/how-to-obscure-scanner-input-text and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819469/hide-input-on-command-line

Comment: I already tried this one, but it hides it, it does not display asterisks

Comment: There is JLine, but it requires native libraries to work on Windows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String password = PasswordField.readPassword("Enter password:");
        System.out.println("Password entered was:" + password);
    }
}


class PasswordField {

   public static String readPassword (String prompt) {
      EraserThread et = new EraserThread(prompt);
      Thread mask = new Thread(et);
      mask.start();

      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String password = "";

      try {
          password = in.readLine();
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
          ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
      et.stopMasking();
      return password;
   }
}   

class EraserThread implements Runnable {
   private boolean stop;

   public EraserThread(String prompt) {
       System.out.print(prompt);
   }

   public void run () {
      while (!stop){
         System.out.print("\010*");
         try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1);
         } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }

   public void stopMasking() {
      this.stop = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! It does work. I just have one question, when executing this code, it displays "Enter passwordµ", I do not know where does that first asterisk come from ?

Comment: BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(System.in)) is actually a better console reader compared to Console and Scanner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console/4645193#4645193 Good password masking solution for using BufferedReader.

Comment: @hacks4life this is basically a hack, "\010" is a backspace character, so this thread is eternally pressing backspace + *, resulting in constant printing of star and deleting it. Once u type anything that is one more character to delete and hence star is left. But because the very first backspace is useless the first star ends up staying printed.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) class is the correct way to read passwords from the command line. However, it doesn't print asterisks, as that would leak information in general (not in the case where a PIN is known to be 4 digits). For something like that, you'd might need a curses library.

Comment: A curses library, what is that ?

Comment: @FlorentP It enables complex terminal interaction. There are several implementations, [here is one.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)