# How to hide and turn my input into asterisk in Java

Tags: java, input, user-input, hide, helper

I'm an ICT student and I need help. Our professor asked us to create a login system. I've already made one, but the problem is that the input is supposed to be hidden. How do I do that?

For example,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
int password;
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
password = x.nextInt();
```

I need to hide the input, and turn that message into an asterisk '*'. Kinda how Facebook does it.

Answer (score 0):

See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12076234/5592976)

Namely:

```
Console console = System.console();

String enteredPassword = new String(console.readPassword("Please enter your password: "));
        
System.out.println("You entered: " + enteredPassword);
```

Answer (score -1):

Good luck, with project.
So, I say put a check box that changes the value of some boolean variable, say, `flag` and the rest is something like this:

```
    String user_name;
    String pass;
    boolean flag;

    void checkBoxPropertyChanged(Action e) {
        flag =! flag;
        changePasswordField();
    }



    void changePasswordField() { 
        String hidden = ""; 
        int len = pass.length();

        for(int i = 0; i<len; i++) 
            hidden += "*"; 
        passwordField.setText((flag) ? pass : hidden); 
    }
```