# Hide Scala readline () input

Tags: scala, stdin

```
println(
"""
    |Enter your name:
    |""".stripMargin)

val myname =scala.io.StdIn.readline()
```

I want the input of the user to appear as ***** so that its not visible to other users.

Comment: Maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076165/how-to-obscure-scanner-input-text. Although this does not appear as asterisks, it shows nothing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The application is asking the users to enter their usernames and passwords in the terminal, l want to makesure the password input is not visible to anyone looking on the screen.