# How can I read numeric passwords in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, password-protection

I am trying to get the user to enter a four digit pin but I don't want it to  be printed out on the screen as they type it. I have tried using `System.console().readPassword();` like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class VirtualATM{
    private static String Details;  
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
            //Create variables & scanner to be used throughout the program.
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean RegisterOrExist = false;
            int cardNo = 0;
            String DirToWriteFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/VirtualATM.txt"; //Get path to write text file to.
            DirToWriteFile.trim();
            File file = new File(DirToWriteFile);
            // if file doesn't exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            //Create writer to write to files.
             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            System.out.println("Enter card number, or type register to register a new card.");
            String register = sc.nextLine();
            if(register.equalsIgnoreCase("register")){
                RegisterOrExist = false;
                RegisterNewCard();
            } else {
            RegisterOrExist = true;
            cardNo = Integer.valueOf(register);
            }
            bw.write(Details);
            //Close the writer.
            bw.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /*** Method for registering a new card **/
    public static void RegisterNewCard(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        int MaxVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int CardNo =  new java.util.Random().nextInt(MaxVal) + 1;
        int balance = new java.util.Random().nextInt(10000) + 1;
        boolean OverDraft = false;
        int OverDraftLimit = 0;
        if(OverDraft = true){
            OverDraftLimit = 250;
        }
        char [] PIN = {};
        System.out.println("Create a FOUR digit pin: ");
        try{
            PIN = System.console().readPassword();
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int P1 = (int) PIN[0];
        int P2 = (int) PIN[1];
        int P3 = (int) PIN[2];
        int P4 = (int) PIN[3];
        int [] PinNo = {P1, P2, P3, P4};
        Details = "Name:   " + name + "   CardNo:   " + CardNo + "   Current Balance:   " + balance + "   overdraft?   " + OverDraft + "   OverDraftLimit:   " + OverDraftLimit + "   pin:   " + PinNo;
    }
}
```

I then try to write the pin `int [] pinNo = {P1, P2, P3, P4}` to a text file using the `BufferedWriter`. I get the following this text in the text file when I input the pin as `2566`:
`[I@42a57993`
Is there another way to read a password without it printing on the screen as the user types?

Comment: `[I@42a57993` is the hash of the array(Object).

Comment: show the BufferedWriter part

Comment: possible duplicate of [Masking password input from the console : Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138411/masking-password-input-from-the-console-java)

Comment: Am I the only one who gets InputMismach Exception when I run this code?

Comment: `int P1 = (int) PIN[0];` is casting `char` to `int`, which is not what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well this line

```
bw.write(Details);
```

is writing the `details` in the file where

```
Details = "..otherdetails..."+"pin:   " + PinNo;
```

shows that you are writing the hash of the array. So simply replace `"pin:   " + PinNo` with
the actual elements of the array

You can simply follow what Rod said or try this

```
Details = "..otherdetails..."+"pin:   " + java.util.Arrays.toString(PinNo)
```

**Tip** - using this makes you password more secure
try like this

```
char[] PIN = System.console.readPassword();  
Arrays.fill(password, ' ');
```

Comment: What does `Arrays.fill(password, ' ');` do?

Comment: it will overwrite any values in the array with blank

Answer (score 2):

**problem:**

```
pin:   " + PinNo;
```

You are actually printing the `memory location` of the array object not the array elements itself

**solution:**

you can get each index of the `PinNo` array and append each of them to the string

```
 "pin:   " + PinNo[0] + PinNo[1] + PinNo[2] + PinNo[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run your code on Eclipse IDE console then it'll not work. It is bug  [System.console() (Java 6.0) returns null when running inside Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429).

You need to run from command prompt or teminal, etc.

For more on this see these post :-

1. [Hide input on command line - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819469/hide-input-on-command-line)
2. [Masking password input from the console - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138411/masking-password-input-from-the-console-java)