# how to hide console input in eclipse in java using console input from user

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
System.out.println("please enter id ");
Console console = System.console();
char[] password = console.readPassword("Enter password");  
Arrays.fill(password, ' ');
```

I am getting  `java.lang.NullPointerException` , I don't know how to get rid of this exception.

Comment: where you get the null pointer exception

Comment: Why are you using fill() to replace all chars in password with blanks?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be bearer of the bad news but that's an Eclipse bug which still hasn't been resolved yet. You can read all about it [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429)
Also the answer by Vijay Shankar in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819469/hide-input-on-command-line) post seems to be a workaround for this.