# how to hide password with java.util.Scanner (no java.io.Console)

Tags: java, command-prompt

in java, how to  hide password with `java.util.Scanner` ?

**CAUTION:** I need not use `java.io.Console` solution

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is your password?");
password = input.nextLine();
```

is it possible to overide Scanner (`org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.StandardOutputStreamLog`)?

is it possible use a other mask system (by an other thread (add `*` by overide)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide input on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819469/hide-input-on-command-line)

Comment: `Scanner` doesnt support this functionality. If you can't use `Console` then youre out of luck

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, read the question please.

Comment: @sgrillon - read the answers he linked to, please. :) The accepted answer isn't always the most applicable.

Comment: My question is "is it possible to overide Scanner or use a other mask system?"

Comment: @sgrillon - And your question does not say that...

Comment: is it write not? `CAUTION: I need not use java.io.Console solution`

Comment: This is probably the specific answer you are looking for. You could create a PasswordScanner which would extend Scanner. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10819532/1787434

Comment: thanks @the_storyteller, is it a solution. Other people do not have any response so juste downvote too quickly

Comment: @Zephyr, you do not read the title?

Comment: @sgrillon - I'm not going to argue with you. Your question was unclear. You edited it after the fact. Either review the [ask] article and learn how to write better questions, or just accept the help people are trying to give you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this within an IDE, your best bet is using a [JPasswordField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html). 
Although this is a GUI solution, it solves the problem without having to use java.io.Console.

Comment: console is not GUI.