# Can i mask/encrypt input text (for ex password) in the windows run.bat file?

Tags: java, batch-file

**Usecase:**
I want to mask input text(mainly password) in run.bat file, i am using java as programming language,overall my major objective is that whenever user provide input for password in run.batch it should be encrypted,is it possible to do so?
Here is my run.batch file :

```
@echo OFF
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
java -jar "stack.jar" -username "stackoverflow" -password "qwerty@567" -configpath "config.ini"
pause
```

Here i want to mask qwerty@567 which is password given by user end
Here is something that i tried but it works only for console

```
import java.io.Console;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Console console = System.console();
char[] passwordArray = console.readPassword("Enter your password: ");
console.printf("Password is: %s%n", new String(passwordArray));
}
}
```

Comment: I am confused. How can you write the password in the batch file when you ask the user to enter it? Do you write the batch file from your java code?

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819469/hide-input-on-command-line

Comment: @Abra my intention is to run .jar file for which i need run.batch in which user will pass parameter as shown above, now i want whenever user will give anything as password in run.batch file it should be encrypted

Comment: if you can't use the Java tools @RR_IL showed, then perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/20343074/917548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password can be an argument to your batch file: `run.bat`.

Modified batch file (from your question)

```
@echo OFF
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
java -jar "stack.jar" -username "stackoverflow" -password %1 -configpath "config.ini"
pause
```

And launch your batch file as:

```
run.bat my_password
```

Now the password does not appear in the batch file.

Comment: can you please elaborate that how to launch run.bat my_password command because as soon as i click on run.batch the program starts running so i am not getting any option for entering the password during runtime

Comment: @RajatKrishnan just replace _my_password_ with the actual password. Then you don't need to ask the user to enter it. In other words, when the user wants to run your batch file, he writes his password on the command line. For example if I want to run your batch file, and my password is GEORGE, I would open a command prompt and write `run.bat GEORGE`

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10, If you take the input directly as a variable in batch, using Set /P, you can change the Color code to black on black for the input using the ANSI Color code `<esc>[30m` (with `<esc>` replaced by the Ansi escape character)

Use `<esc>[0m` after taking input to reset the color.

Comment: Thanks for support,but i guess this is not something i am looking for

Comment: Given it achieves the objective as laid out in your question, it would be useful to clarify in what way this is not what your looking for. I notice in one of your comments you mention encrypting the password. If this is what you are looking for, you should update your question to reflect that.

Comment: its clear sir that i want to encrypt my password but can you show that how are you passing the command in run.batch with the given solution?

Comment: In your question you use the terms `mask` and `not be visible` in reference to `Input`, you do use the phrase `Encryption` anywhere within your question, hence why I recommend editing the question, as it is not clear.

Comment: [demonstration of the suggested input masking](https://pastebin.com/G7dPerim)

Comment: Ok its done, any suggestions now, like how to achieve the asked operation?

Comment: Depending on the level of security you need, Particularly if encryption is genuinely required, Batch is not the right language to be using. [Powershell offers better tools for this task](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/)